# How to query using variables

Tags: entries, search, queries

I'm having issues with getting results from a query. I have 2 search parameters which i have set to variables. I would like to match both of these to get results.

At the moment the query is returning zero results. I think this is because it is turning the variables into strings. Replacing the variables with hardcoded values does return results.

```
{% set queryKeyword = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set queryLocation = craft.request.getParam('l') %}

{%
    set entries = craft.entries.section('schools').find({
       search: 'body:queryKeyword categories:queryLocation'
    })
%}
```

I have tried:

```
{%
    set entries = craft.entries.section('schools').find({
       search: 'body:' + queryKeyword + 'categories:' + queryLocation,
    })
%}
```

This doesn't work.

I'm very new to Craft CMS and am not very experienced in PHP/MySQL so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong string concatination operator. `~` is the twig string concatination operator (vs `.` for php and `+` for javascript).

Try this:

```
{%
  set entries = craft.entries.section('schools').find({
   search: 'body:' ~ queryKeyword ~ ' categories:' ~ queryLocation,
  })
%}
```

Comment: Also, don't forget the space before "categories"... Although I'm not sure it's possible to conduct a search through related categories.

Comment: @LindseyD - good catch that space.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "categories" field is in fact a [categories field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories-fields) then I'd recommend to
use the [`relatedTo`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) parameter to filter by that category instead of throwing everything into the [`search`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching#templating) parameter.

```
{% set queryLocation = craft.request.getParam('l') %}
{% set queryKeyword = craft.request.getParam('q') %}

{# Set relationParam only if the param is set and a category with that slug exists #}
{% set category = craft.categories.group('location').slug(queryLocation).first() %}
{% set relationParam = queryLocation and category ? {targetElement: category} : '' %}

{# Set searchParam only if the param is set #}
{% set searchParam = queryKeyword ? 'body:' ~ queryKeyword : '' %}

{# Get the filtered entries #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(relationParam).search(searchParam) %}
```